# How can I automatically add color to a log.txt file?

Tags: logging

I look after logs from various sources, some of which are difficult to read, especially with ADHD. Is there a known way to paste or upload a text file and have it automatically colorized for readability?

e.g. text inside of double quotes gets colored green for a string and it takes common conventions like ERROR/INFO and makes them red/grey.

This question is specifically about logs that have already been created, not an integrated solution that colorizes logs as they are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of things that your text reader can handle for you.

If you are using Visual Studio Code, check out https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emilast.LogFileHighlighter

Comment: Most of this extension's functionality is now included in VS Code 1.20+ by default. So all I had to do was rename my file from `xyz.txt` to `xyz.log` and it has been colorized. Thank you!